# Generated FindBy() always returns null

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a dataset (myds) that contains table (assests).

When I try to find a row in (assest) by using the auto-generated `FindBy()` it always returns `null`.

```
MyDS.AssestsRow asRow = this.myds.Assests.FindBy(pk1,pk2,pk3);

if (asRow == null)
   return "No Row Found";
```

I'm 100% sure that I have row in the table that matches my query but this `FindBy()` always returns null!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here we go,

Although I couldn't figure it out yet but I found that after declaring Assets datatable and using AssetsTableAdapter to get data into it, only then, I was able to retrieve the row I wanted.

So instead of doing this:

```
MyDS.AssestsRow asRow = this.myds.Assests.FindBy(pk1,pk2,pk3);

if (asRow == null)
   return "No Row Found";
```

I did that:

```
MyDS.AssestsDataTable assetsDataTable = this.assestsTableAdapter.GetData();
MyDS.AssestsRow asRow = assetsDataTable.FindBy(pk1,pk2,pk3);

if (asRow == null)
   return "No Row Found";
```

Anyone could tell me WHY?

Comment: It didn't work because I removed the generated statement from the Form_Load event that fills Assets. So when I was trying to find the row, I was actually accessing an empty table!